# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'name' when using Streamlit

Tags: python, image-processing, streamlit

I've been trying to replicate the demo website from this [repo](https://github.com/Mukosame/Anime2Sketch) using Streamlit.

But I'm stuck when I'm going to process the image with the model. The error message is `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'name'`. But in `data.py` or the code to read the image there is no `'name'` attribute. Or I'm missing something here?

This is the snippet code

**streamlitdemo.py**

```py
@st.cache()
def load_model():
    gpu_ids=[]
    model = create_model(gpu_ids)
    model.eval()
    return model

a = 'wave.jpg'
b = 'building.jpg'
c = 'test_samples/madoka.jpg'

def anime2sketch(img_input, load_size=512):
    img, aus_resize = read_img_path(img_input.name, load_size)
    model = load_model()
    aus_tensor = model(img)
    aus_img = tensor_to_img(aus_tensor)
    image_pil = Image.fromarray(aus_img)
    image_pil = image_pil.resize(aus_resize, Image.BICUBIC)
    return image_pil
```

**demo.py**

```py
.
.
.
def read_img_path(path, load_size):
    """read tensors from a given image path
    Parameters:
        path (str)     -- input image path
        load_size(int) -- the input size. If <= 0, don't resize
    """
    img = Image.open(path).convert('RGB')
    aus_resize = None
    if load_size > 0:
        aus_resize = img.size
    transform = get_transform(load_size=load_size)
    image = transform(img)
    return image.unsqueeze(0), aus_resize
```

**model.py**

```py
.
.
.
def create_model(gpu_ids=[]):
    """Create a model for anime2sketch
    hardcoding the options for simplicity
    """
    norm_layer = functools.partial(nn.InstanceNorm2d, affine=False, track_running_stats=False)
    net = UnetGenerator(3, 1, 8, 64, norm_layer=norm_layer, use_dropout=False)
    ckpt = torch.load('weights/netG.pth')
    for key in list(ckpt.keys()):
        if 'module.' in key:
            ckpt[key.replace('module.', '')] = ckpt[key]
            del ckpt[key]
    net.load_state_dict(ckpt)
    if len(gpu_ids) > 0:
        assert(torch.cuda.is_available())
        net.to(gpu_ids[0])
        net = torch.nn.DataParallel(net, gpu_ids)  # multi-GPUs
    return net
```

But, when I'm hardcode the path with `a/b/c` variable, the model work properly. And I've already change `read_img_path(img_input.name, load_size)` to `read_img_path(img_input, load_size)` and I got `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'wave'` error message.

This is the output when I'm hardcode the path

[image: result]

In that repo, the author already provide demo website but using Gradio. When I tried to run the demo code with Gradio it is work properly. I'm using the same code from the author, but I tweak it a little bit.

Thank you.

Comment: Did you try and post on the StreamLit forums? https://discuss.streamlit.io/